# remove duplication in List python

Tags: python

I wrote a code that removes duplication in a string, but the problem is in the condition I have an error: index is out of range!
The input is: rooobert  and output: robert

```
n = list(input())
s=[]
for i in range(0,len(n)-1):
    if n[i] == n[i+1]:
     n.remove(n[i])

print(n)
```

Comment: What do you thing happens when you remove elements from the list, while `i` will still come from range based on the original length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing from that same string/list; it starts with length `n`, and whenever you remove a character the length goes down by `1`, hence you'll get out of range.

You can change your code to use a new string for the result:

```py
newList = []
for i in range(0,len(n)-1):
   if n[i] != n[i+1]: # notice the flip of the comparison here
      newList += n[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by tracking the previous element and then creating a newlist. Deleting from the list that you are iterating is generally a bad idea.

```
n = list("rooobert")
s=[]
prev = None
for i in range(0,len(n)):
    if n[i] != prev:
     s.append(n[i])
    prev = n[i]
print(s)
```

OUTPUT

```
['r', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't']
```